# docker asp.net log configuration to enable log error too

Tags: asp.net, docker, .net-core, mountebank

the application uses `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging`

```
_logger.LogError
_logger.LogInformation
```

this is configured in appsettings.json

```
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  },
```

then I am using mountebank as config server.
at imposter file

```
 "propertySources": [
                {
                  "source": {
                    "Logging.Console.LogLevel.Default": "Information",
}
```

How do I enable all log to include error as well?